# Error with multiple params in entity, symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I had given the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to BackendBundle\Entity\Notification::sendSystemMessage() 
must be an instance of BackendBundle\Entity\BackendBundle\Entity\User, instance of 
Proxies\__CG__\BackendBundle\Entity\User given
```

the method I have in my Notification.php class is:

```
/**
     * Send System message, to be used after creating a blank one
     *
     * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\User $reciever
     *
     * @param string $message
     *
     * @return Notification
     */
    public function sendSystemMessage(BackendBundle\Entity\User $reciever, $message)
    {
        $this->setReciever($reciever);
        $this->setMessage($message);
        $this->setTimestamp(new \DateTime());
        $this->setReaded(false);
        $this->setSystemMessage(true);

        return $this;
    }
```

when I use the setters and getters like setReciever, it works perfectly, but when I try to call multiple params I got this error, I'm I making a mistake or there can't be a multiple parameters method in the entities classes?

Comment: That error message comes from code somewhere else, where you call the sendSystemMessage() function. Your $reciever argument has the wrong type.

Comment: That was my first idea, but I call the setReciever method with same validation and it works well

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show the code where you compare the two with the same argument being sent and also the function description for setReciever?

Comment: Add a back slash to the beginning ofyour User type hint.  Better yet, add a use statement and simplify the type hint to User.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: That was the problem, damn backslash, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to Cerad.

My problem was that I had

```
public function sendSystemMessage(BackendBundle\Entity\User $reciever, $message)
```

when I needed

```
public function sendSystemMessage(\BackendBundle\Entity\User $reciever, $message)
```

that backslash was getting me a different path for the User class